# Passing variable to metadata for Sugar CRM Filter php

Tags: php, filter, metadata, sugarcrm

In Sugar I'm trying to create a filter in a Cases module that will show cases where the assigned user of the case is the current user.
To this I am trying to pass the ID of the current user to the viewdefs array.
It is expecting a String value like shown:

```
'$owner' => array('$in' => array('<owner ID>') )
```

I've tried to pass the value in a couple of different ways without success.

VERSION 1

```
global $current_user;
'filter_definition' => array(array('$owner' => array('$in' => array($current_user->id)))
```

VERSION 2

```
global $current_user;
$idArr = array();
$idArr[] = $current_user->id;
'filter_definition' => array(array('$owner' => array('$in' => $idArr)))
```

Sugar is not liking either way and tells me the value passed is invalid. How do I get Sugar to accept this $current_user->id value??

Comment: in <bean>.php find the method get_list_view_data, there you can override the query of the listview

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how that will help? 
I would have thought that building the viewdef for the filter was

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how that will help? 
I need to pass the $current_user->id to the $owner variable as stated in this doc. However, there are no examples shown
http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.6/UI_Model/Views/Filters/

Comment: I just found the answer so will post it as there is no documentation on it.

To pass $current_use->id to the $owner variable leave the value blank as shown. Sugar is able to interpet that the current user is the assigned user

$owner => ' '